# JsonObject received from android service call is null at .net service

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, web-services

I have written a service in asp.net MVC which accepts stringified Json object as a parameter and I am trying to consume from my android code

this is service method

```
public JsonResult saveDataInSession(string jsonObjSend)
{
    JsonResult jsonResult = null;
    List<OnlineUserDetails> lstValue = new List<OnlineUserDetails>();
    OnlineUserDetails UserDetails = new OnlineUserDetails();
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    UserDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineUserDetails>(jsonData);
    UserDetails.LoginId = UserDetails.EmaillId;
    UserLoginAndSignUp UserLoginAndSignUp = new UserLoginAndSignUp();
    string result = UserLoginAndSignUp.SaveDetails(UserDetails);
    jsonResult = Json(UserDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsonResult;
}
```

And this is how i am sending the json object from android

```
jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
try{
    jsonObjSend.put("FirstName", firstname.getText().toString());
    jsonObjSend.put("LastName", lastname.getText().toString());
    jsonObjSend.put("EmaillId", emailid.getText().toString());
    jsonObjSend.put("Password", password.getText().toString());
    jsonObjSend.put("MobileNumber", mobilenumber.getText().toString());
    //jsonObjSend.put("Login_RememberMe", "true");
    //
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And making an HttpRequest call like

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

    StringEntity se=null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);           
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException  e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    se.setContentType("application/json");
    se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
    // Set HTTP parameters
    httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

But whenever i try to consume webservice by passing jsonobject i am receiving null.

What's the error??

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set **dataType = json** when posting request along with json data

In your case I suppose there is an option to call something like this:

```
se.setDataType("json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ByteArrayEntity` and not `StringEntity` to `httpPostRequest.setEntity()

Try the following code:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
        response = mHttpClient.execute(request);
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```